# how to use choices argument inside a class as a value of radio input in Django template

Tags: python, django

I want to know how to define choices values to a radio button in the Django template.
Here is my **models.py**

```
RATING_CHOICES = ((1, "Weak"), (2, "Average"), (3, "Good"), (4, "Excellent"))
...
class Answer(models.Model):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)   
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=RATING_CHOICES, default=1)
```

In the template I want to assign values of my RARING_CHOICES to radio in a loop condition.

```
{% for question in questions %}
<li>{{ question }}</li>
<ul>
<input type="radio" value="">
<input type="radio" value="">
<input type="radio" value="">
<input type="radio" value="">
  </ul>

{% endfor %}
```

**Views.py**

```
def index(request):
    context = { "questions": Question.objects.all(),
                "answers": Answer.objects.all(),
                "departments": Department.objects.all(),
                "semesters": Semester.objects.all(),
                "teachers": Teacher.objects.all(),
                "subjects": Subject.objects.all(),}
    return render(request, "evaluation/index.html", context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass RATING_CHOICE value in context from views

```
RATING_CHOICES = ((1, "Weak"), (2, "Average"), (3, "Good"), (4, "Excellent"))
context = { "questions": Question.objects.all(),
                "answers": Answer.objects.all(),
                "departments": Department.objects.all(),
                "semesters": Semester.objects.all(),
                "teachers": Teacher.objects.all(),
                "subjects": Subject.objects.all(),
                "rating_choices":RATING_CHOICES,
            }
```

In template run a for loop over rating_choices

```
{% for question in questions %}
    <li>{{ question }}</li>
    <ul>

    {% for choice in rating_choices %}
       <input type="radio" value="{{choice.0}}">{{choice.1}}
    {% endfor %}

    </ul>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It worked but, what about RATING_CHOICES in models.py?

Comment: you can import it from models.py like from .models import RATING_CHOICES

Comment: There is one problem Mr. Kumar, when I select a choice for one question and select another one for another question my selected radio switch from the first question to the second one?

Comment: Name should be different in every case. It should be like <input type="radio" value="{{choice.0}}" name="question_{{question.id}}">

Comment: I do not know how to access name="question_{{question.id}}" in my views. The other field are simple for example teacher = request.POST.get('teacher') but this one is tricky for me.